# Can I create a "insert FIXME / CHANGED list" bundle in Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate2

In  Textmante 2, I have a very usefull bundle: `todo ->`, this inserts:

```
=begin
 TODO:
=end
```

then, when I use “show TODO list” bunlde I can see TODO, FIXME, CHANGED… code, but I can’t insert FIXME or CHANGED when I type `fixme ->` or `changed ->` as I do with `todo ->`

Can I create a `insert CHANGED list` bundle with Textmate 2?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is so easy as create a new "command type" item from menu:

From Edit Bundle. menu File -> New, and then choose "Command" type, as is in "insert TODO list", then I have copied/pasted from `insert TODO list`, but I supose there is a way to not DRY (Dont Repeat mYself), but in Textmate i don't know how to don't DRY

[image]

[image]